# Can Meta create a Twitter clone?

Tags: united-states, copyright, internet

Meta is about to release an app called Threads that has been labeled by news sources as a Twitter rival or Twitter clone.

I don't know how similar Threads actually is to Twitter, but hypothetically if it were almost identical, would that be legal? More generally, can anyone just copy an existing website (without copying the code or images)? Could I make a website that lets people post pictures like Instagram but call it MyPics? How similar do two websites or apps have to be before there's a legal/copyright issue?

Comment: You’re asking about the wrong kind of intellectual property. It’s patents that protect inventions against duplication, not copyrights.

Comment: The trouble with this question is that it asks about copying things which weren't original and which have been copied widely without issue, rather than copying genuinely novel stuff. There's nothing novel about posting pictures or messages online, and lots of sites did it before Twitter and Instagram. Flickr was hugely popular as a social image-sharing site before Instagram was a thing. Twitter was a bit more novel in its focus on short messages and things like retweets and quote-tweets, but drew heavily on blogging and earlier sites' status updates, and has been widely copied since.

Comment: Truth Social is almost exactly a clone of Twitter, I'm sure it's more similar than Threads will be.

Comment: @user2259438 I'd mention that Truth Social was caught using the Mastodon codebase without attribution, but had the good grace to fix things promptly when challenged.

Comment: I would just take a look at tiktok vs facebook and youtube shorts.

Comment: @user2259438 There's a Twitter for people who think Twitter isn't right-wing enough?

Comment: Looks like Twitter is suing. But it's over trade secrets (because apparently a lot of ex-Twitter employees went to Meta), so it's only relevant to the specific case, not the general question.

Comment: @Styxsksu Just because TikTok, Facebook, and YouTube Shorts all exist, does not mean that legal action is not possible.  Often, companies decide not to engage in legal action even when that option is available.  Of course, I'm not suggesting that there is a legal issue, just that the argument presented does not support a conclusion (IMO).

Answer (score 37):

> More generally, can anyone just copy an existing website (without
> copying the code or images)?

Yes.

> Could I make a website that lets people post pictures like Instagram
> but call it MyPics?

Yes.

In general, copyright protects particular expressions of ideas, not higher level ideas or concepts.

Comment: I am confused by the wording. Wouldn't a _website_ (probably more like a _web-application_ ) for pictures count as a "particular expression of an idea" rather than the higher level concept of 'a place for people to share visual media' or something of the kind?

Comment: @marts *A particular* website, comprising its layout, content, and source code, is a copyrightable "particular expression". You can't copy another website wholesale, but you can make another implementation of the same idea. It's the same with other works, you can write a book about a boy who goes to a wizard school, for example, without infringing upon the copyright for Harry Potter.

Comment: @marts A "website that you store images on" has to be a website, and has to let you store images.  Those are *intrinsic* requirements for its function, which protects/limits them from falling under copyright or patent — unlike the *specific methods* used to do so, or the branding/layout, since there can be multiple implementations that will achieve the same result.  This simultaneously attempts to reduce monopolies (no one can patent "mobile phone" as a concept), and incentivize innovation (since you can patent specific *types* of mobile phone, and competitors have to invent **new** types)

Answer (score 17):

Copyright applies to creative expressions, not abstract ideas. Copying the general  functionality of an application is not a copyright violation. Only copying the code, art assets etc. is.

However, under some circumstances, an idea can be *patented*. That is if that idea is a new "invention". It is possible for companies like Twitter or Instagram to protect certain features of their websites they invented using patents. In fact, [Twitter does that](https://patents.justia.com/company/twitter). But patents have some limitations:

- They can only protect what's actually new. When someone did something like that before, then that is called "prior art" and it invalidates the patent. For example, you could not patent "A website that allows users to upload images" today, because websites that allow users to upload images have already been invented and exist for ages.
- And because you can't patent something that already exists, you have to be really specific in your patent description. Which means people can get around it by doing things slightly different than claimed in the patent. For example, if your patent says "Uploaded images are displayed on the left side of the screen", then someone could avoid infringing it by displaying uploaded images on the *right* side of the screen.
- Patents have a rather short expiration time. How long exactly depends on the country and the type of patent, but they are generally not longer than 20 years.

Comment: Ideas can't be patented. You need much more than an idea for that. And you can't get a patent on the effect of an invention, but only on a specific method. The "idea" of twitter would be completely unpatentable.

Comment: @gnasher729 I made it a bit specific that in order for an idea to be patentable, the idea must be an "invention".

Comment: The idea also has to be non-obvious. Online discussion and chat were almost an immediate creation when the Internet took form.

Comment: Probably the only thing that was innovative about Twitter when it was first created was linking it to SMS. Does it even do that any more, or does everyone use the app?

Comment: @Barmar Tweeting from SMS has been shut down in most countries back in 2019. Facebook copied that feature for a while, so even that feature isn't protected

Comment: The very short character limit was touted itself as a feature for a long time. I recall lots of articles claiming that it was why the culture of twitter was the way it was.

Comment: I wonder how many of [twitter's many patents](https://insights.greyb.com/twitter-patents/) Meta is likely to infringe with Threads?

Comment: @user3490 I am sure a company like Meta has several patent lawyers involved in their development processes to make sure they don't. Or if they do, that they can get away with it, because the infringement happens server-sided and it's impossible to prove for an outside observer that it happens.

Comment: @philipp do source code leaks count as proof?